# Injecting code into methods before and after main execution block

Tags: java, performance, code-injection

I have a couple of classes that implements an a specific `interface`, something as follows (this is obviously a very simplified version, but gets the point across):

```
public interface Talk {
  void sayIt();
}
```

First implementation of `Talk`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SayHello implements Talk {

  static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SayHello.class);

  public SayHello() {}

  public void sayIt() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

Second implementation of `Talk`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SayGoodbye implements Talk {

  static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SayHello.class);

  public SayGoodbye() {}

  public void sayIt() {
    System.out.println("GoodBye");
  }

}
```

Now in the `sayIt()` method I want to implement some trace level logging and some method execution timers, which I can simply do something as follows:

```
public void sayIt() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOG.trace("Executing sayIT for implementation {} , start time at {}.", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), startTime);
    System.out.println("Hello");
    LOG.trace("sayIT for implementation {} took {} milliseconds to execute.", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
}
```

Problem is that I would need to copy-n-paste this into each implementation of the `sayIt()` method for each `class` that implements the `Talk` interface and I don't really want to do that because...

1. It creates a lot of duplication.
2. With more implementations you start having a maintenance headache, especially when you decide to change the implementation slightly.
3. I'm lazy and like to write as little code as possible whilst reusing as much as possible.

So here is the question .... how would I achieve the goal of writing once, use multiple times? Method timing is one application, but I really just want to be able to "inject" code in the beginning and end of the method.

I'm really looking for a **working example** (not just a link to more links) of something that may work (I'm guessing something like [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), but I've been having endless hassle trying to get it to work with Gradle ... might have just attempt a Maven implementation)

Oh, yes I could instead of adding the code to `sayIt()` add it to the code invoking `sayIt()`, for example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeOtherClass {

  static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeOtherClass.class);

  public SomeOtherClass() {}

  public void letsHaveAConversation() {
    List<Talk> talks = new ArrayList<>();
    talks.add(new SayHello());
    talks.add(new SayGoodbye());
    for (Talk talking : talks) { 
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOG.trace("Executing sayIT for implementation {} , start time at {}.", talking.getClass().getSimpleName(), startTime);
        talking.sayIt();
        LOG.trace("sayIT for implementation {} took {} milliseconds to execute.", talking.getClass().getSimpleName(), System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }
  }

}
```

This will work, but not if I have multiple locations from where `sayIt()` is being called.

Comment: More broadly, a Decorator.

Comment: @Kayaman, yes you are 100% correct, that is what AspectJ attempts to do. Spring also has a AOP framework, but I'm unfortunately not working with Spring in this implementation. As mention, what I'm looking for is a working example. Just a side note ... I've tinkered with AspectJ, but I've been having trouble getting it working. The reason my question is a bit broad however is that I don't want it to specifically be an AspectJ implementation question as I'm interested in different suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just wrap the `sayIt` call inside abstract class common method?

```
abstract class AbstractTalk implements Talk {
    public void sayIt() {
        trace();
        startMeasure();

        doSayIt();

        stopMeasure();
    }

    abstract protected doSayIt(); // here implement the logic
}
```

Comment: Good point, this solution works quite well and it does not come with the black magic of code injection. The only problem this would introduce (at least in my scenario) is more of a logging issue. The Log output would be against `AbstractTalk` and not  against `SayHello` or `SayGoodbye`. Though I guess one could always use something like `String callingThread = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();` to get that information.

Comment: you can always provide a protected constructor with `logger` parameter and provide proper logger implementation when creating child classes

Comment: Yes, or add another abstract method that returns a `Logger`